# Homebrew error with MacVim on OSX Lion

Tags: python, packages, macvim, make, homebrew

I am trying to install Macvim with Homebrew on an OSX machine running Lion.

After installing iconv at /opt/local/bin/iconv I get the following error in the log:

```
Error: Can't run /Applications/Xcode.app/usr/bin/xcodebuild (no such file).
```

Here is the full trace if you need it:

```
    familys-imac:~ Paul-Arthur$ brew install macvim
    Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
    Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
    Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
    ==> Downloading https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/tarball/snapshot-64
    File already downloaded in /Users/Paul-Arthur/Library/Caches/Homebrew
    ==> ./configure --with-features=huge --with-tlib=ncurses --enable-multibyte --with-macarchs=x86_64 --enable-perlinterp --enable-pythoninterp --enable-rubyinterp --enable-tclinterp
    ==> cd src/MacVim/icons && make getenvy
    ==> make
    Starting make in the src directory.
    If there are problems, cd to the src directory and run make there
    cd src && make first
    mkdir objects
    CC="gcc -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp    -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1  " srcdir=. sh ./osdef.sh
    creating auto/pathdef.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -fobjc-exceptions -o objects/gui_macvim.o MacVim/gui_macvim.m
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -fobjc-exceptions -o objects/MMBackend.o MacVim/MMBackend.m
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/MacVim.o MacVim/MacVim.m
    /opt/local/bin/perl -e 'unless ( $] >= 5.005 ) { for (qw(na defgv errgv)) { print "#define PL_$_ $_\n" }}' > auto/if_perl.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -O2   -DPERL_DARWIN -I/opt/local/include -no-cpp-precomp -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/opt/local/include  -I/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level/CORE  -o objects/if_perlsfio.o if_perlsfio.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -DPYTHON_HOME=\"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6\"  -o objects/if_python.o if_python.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/if_tcl.o if_tcl.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1    -o objects/if_ruby.o if_ruby.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/os_macosx.o os_macosx.m
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/os_mac_conv.o os_mac_conv.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/netbeans.o netbeans.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/main.o main.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/memfile.o memfile.c
    cd xxd; CC="gcc" CFLAGS="-DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1" \
            make -f Makefile
    gcc -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1  -DUNIX -o xxd xxd.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/buffer.o buffer.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/blowfish.o blowfish.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/charset.o charset.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/diff.o diff.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/digraph.o digraph.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/edit.o edit.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/eval.o eval.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/ex_cmds.o ex_cmds.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/ex_cmds2.o ex_cmds2.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/ex_docmd.o ex_docmd.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/ex_eval.o ex_eval.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/ex_getln.o ex_getln.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/fileio.o fileio.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/fold.o fold.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/getchar.o getchar.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/hardcopy.o hardcopy.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/hashtab.o hashtab.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/if_cscope.o if_cscope.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/if_xcmdsrv.o if_xcmdsrv.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/mark.o mark.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/memline.o memline.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/menu.o menu.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/message.o message.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/misc1.o misc1.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/misc2.o misc2.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/move.o move.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/mbyte.o mbyte.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/normal.o normal.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/ops.o ops.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/option.o option.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/os_unix.o os_unix.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/pathdef.o auto/pathdef.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/popupmnu.o popupmnu.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/quickfix.o quickfix.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/regexp.o regexp.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/screen.o screen.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/search.o search.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/sha256.o sha256.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/spell.o spell.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/syntax.o syntax.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/tag.o tag.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/term.o term.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/ui.o ui.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/undo.o undo.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/window.o window.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/gui.o gui.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/gui_beval.o gui_beval.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/pty.o pty.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -O2   -DPERL_DARWIN -I/opt/local/include -no-cpp-precomp -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/opt/local/include  -I/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level/CORE  -o objects/if_perl.o auto/if_perl.c
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIM_Msg’:
    if_perl.c:1016: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIM_SetOption’:
    if_perl.c:1061: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIM_DoCommand’:
    if_perl.c:1086: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIM_Eval’:
    if_perl.c:1110: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIM_Buffers’:
    if_perl.c:1147: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIM_Windows’:
    if_perl.c:1214: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIWIN_DESTROY’:
    if_perl.c:1259: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIWIN_Buffer’:
    if_perl.c:1289: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIWIN_SetHeight’:
    if_perl.c:1323: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIWIN_Cursor’:
    if_perl.c:1365: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIBUF_DESTROY’:
    if_perl.c:1417: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIBUF_Name’:
    if_perl.c:1447: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIBUF_Number’:
    if_perl.c:1485: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIBUF_Count’:
    if_perl.c:1519: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIBUF_Get’:
    if_perl.c:1553: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIBUF_Set’:
    if_perl.c:1601: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIBUF_Delete’:
    if_perl.c:1665: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘XS_VIBUF_Append’:
    if_perl.c:1745: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    if_perl.c: In function ‘boot_VIM’:
    if_perl.c:1813: warning: unused variable ‘Perl___notused’
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   version.c -o objects/version.o
      gcc   -L.   -L.        -arch x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib  -o Vim objects/buffer.o objects/blowfish.o objects/charset.o objects/diff.o objects/digraph.o objects/edit.o objects/eval.o objects/ex_cmds.o objects/ex_cmds2.o objects/ex_docmd.o objects/ex_eval.o objects/ex_getln.o objects/fileio.o objects/fold.o objects/getchar.o objects/hardcopy.o objects/hashtab.o  objects/if_cscope.o objects/if_xcmdsrv.o objects/mark.o objects/memline.o objects/menu.o objects/message.o objects/misc1.o objects/misc2.o objects/move.o objects/mbyte.o objects/normal.o objects/ops.o objects/option.o objects/os_unix.o objects/pathdef.o objects/popupmnu.o objects/quickfix.o objects/regexp.o objects/screen.o objects/search.o objects/sha256.o objects/spell.o objects/syntax.o  objects/tag.o objects/term.o objects/ui.o objects/undo.o objects/version.o objects/window.o objects/gui.o objects/gui_beval.o objects/pty.o objects/gui_macvim.o objects/MMBackend.o objects/MacVim.o   objects/if_perl.o objects/if_perlsfio.o objects/if_python.o  objects/if_tcl.o objects/if_ruby.o objects/os_macosx.o objects/os_mac_conv.o  objects/netbeans.o  objects/main.o objects/memfile.o -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon      -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa    -L/opt/local/lib  -fstack-protector  -L/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lutil -lc -framework Python  -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework Tcl -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework Ruby   
    link.sh: OK, linking works, let's try omitting a few libraries.
    link.sh: See auto/link.log for details.
    link.sh: Trying to omit the iconv library...
    link.sh: Vim DOES need the iconv library.
    link.sh: Trying to omit the perl library...
    link.sh: Vim DOES need the perl library.
    link.sh: Trying to omit the dl library...
    link.sh: Vim doesn't need the dl library!
    link.sh: Trying to omit the pthread library...
    link.sh: Vim doesn't need the pthread library!
    link.sh: Trying to omit the m library...
    link.sh: Vim doesn't need the m library!
    creating auto/pathdef.c
    gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1   -o objects/pathdef.o auto/pathdef.c
    link.sh: Using auto/link.sed file to omit a few libraries
      gcc   -L.   -L.        -arch x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib  -o Vim objects/buffer.o objects/blowfish.o objects/charset.o objects/diff.o objects/digraph.o objects/edit.o objects/eval.o objects/ex_cmds.o objects/ex_cmds2.o objects/ex_docmd.o objects/ex_eval.o objects/ex_getln.o objects/fileio.o objects/fold.o objects/getchar.o objects/hardcopy.o objects/hashtab.o  objects/if_cscope.o objects/if_xcmdsrv.o objects/mark.o objects/memline.o objects/menu.o objects/message.o objects/misc1.o objects/misc2.o objects/move.o objects/mbyte.o objects/normal.o objects/ops.o objects/option.o objects/os_unix.o objects/pathdef.o objects/popupmnu.o objects/quickfix.o objects/regexp.o objects/screen.o objects/search.o objects/sha256.o objects/spell.o objects/syntax.o  objects/tag.o objects/term.o objects/ui.o objects/undo.o objects/version.o objects/window.o objects/gui.o objects/gui_beval.o objects/pty.o objects/gui_macvim.o objects/MMBackend.o objects/MacVim.o   objects/if_perl.o objects/if_perlsfio.o objects/if_python.o  objects/if_tcl.o objects/if_ruby.o objects/os_macosx.o objects/os_mac_conv.o  objects/netbeans.o  objects/main.o objects/memfile.o -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon      -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa    -L/opt/local/lib  -fstack-protector  -L/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc -framework Python  -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework Tcl -framework CoreFoundation -framework Ruby   
    link.sh: Linked fine with a few libraries omitted
    xcodebuild -project MacVim/MacVim.xcodeproj ARCHS="x86_64" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH="NO"
    Error: Can't run /Applications/Xcode.app/usr/bin/xcodebuild (no such file).
    make[1]: *** [macvim] Error 1
    make: *** [first] Error 2
    ==> Exit Status: 2
    http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/macvim.rb#L56
    ==> Environment
    HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8.1
    HEAD: f36c6d7b5db46162ae15ba32bafac22b320cadeb
    HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
    HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
    Hardware: dual-core 64-bit penryn
    OS X: 10.7.3
    Kernel Architecture: x86_64
    Xcode: 4.1
    GCC-4.0: N/A
    GCC-4.2: build 5666
    LLVM: build 2335
    Clang: 2.1 build 163
    MacPorts or Fink? /opt/local/bin/port
    X11: /usr/X11
    System Ruby: 1.8.7-249
    /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    Which Perl:   /opt/local/bin/perl => /opt/local/bin/perl5.12
    Which Python: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python => /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
    Which Ruby:   /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    ==> Build Flags
    LD: /usr/bin/llvm-gcc => /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
    MAKEFLAGS: -j2

    Error: Failed executing: make 
    These existing issues may help you:
        https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10121
        https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10124
        https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10490
        https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10580
        https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10589
    Otherwise, please report the bug:
        https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/checklist-before-filing-a-new-issue
```

Comment: If got iconv installed, I still get a similar error. Also, being 16 year old, this doesn't all always make sense. I had no idea what iconv was before having to read about it after this.

Comment: Edited the post to reflect this. Is it a problem with perl?

Comment: With build logs, you'll want to always search for the lines that contain error and also read the lines around them, the earliest error that you can find is usually the problem. Given that you have RFID spoofing and that kind of things on your blog, as well as code, I would've suspected you to be more aware of this. Check out ggustafsson's answer as he might be onto something, as well as slhck's comment there...

Comment: Could your `xcodebuild` still be in `/usr/bin`? Add the output of `xcode-select -print-path` to your question please. (And you can ping me with `@slhck`)

Comment: @slhck this is the output :    /Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: @slhck also running 'xcodebuild' gives this: Error: Can't run /Applications/Xcode.app/usr/bin/xcodebuild (no such file).

Comment: Where is `xcodebuild` then? Is it maybe in `/Developer/usr/bin`? Your configuration thinks that Xcode is in `/Applications` while it's probably somewhere else. Maybe try to reinstall Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Can't run /Applications/Xcode.app/usr/bin/xcodebuild (no such file).
```

That's the problem. Run `brew update`, make sure you have the latest version of Xcode and try again. I'm guessing you must have the latest version of Xcode for the current homebrew formula to work.

Comment: Don't you think this also involves `xcode-select` if migrating from an older version?

Comment: I don't have a clue of what messes things up or how to solve it. `/usr/bin/xcodebuild` should run and not `/Applications/Xcode.app/usr/bin/xcodebuild`.

Comment: brew update did not do anything, it had been done before. Thanks anyway.